# jquery csv function, how to return a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code. I am able to call the function "titlename" and execute the StatList function to read the CSV file. However I am not able to return any value.From browsing online I found that this question might be related to Ajax, but I donot know Ajax. I want to return the "titles" variable in the following example.

```
function titlename(title_number)
{   
    jQuery.get('TitleName.csv', function StatList(data) 
    { 
            var titles = new Array();
        var title_array = jQuery.csv(undefined, undefined, '\r\n')(data);
        for (var i=0; i<title_number.length; i++){
            for (var j = 1; j< title_array.length; j++)
            {
                var tmp_compare = title_array[j].slice(0,title_array[j].length-1);
                if(tmp_compare.toString() == title_number[i]){
                    var title = title_array[j][(title_array[j].length-1)];
                    //console.log(title);
                    titles.push(title);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return titles;
    });
}
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, your `titlename` function completes and returns before the fetching of the csv file is done.

Comment: thx, I am able to see that from the execution. Can you tell me what can be done in the above example to return the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since AJAX is asynchronous you cannot simply return the value from a call to `titlename`. What you could do to use the information once it arrives is call another function and pass in the data you wanted to fetch as an argument. You can either process the data on the spot or process it in the function that you run. For demonstrative purposes, I'll leave your code where it was.

Here's an example of a potential next step:

```
var handleTitleData = function(titles){
     // Do whatever you want now that you have the titles
}
var titlename = function(title_number){   
    jQuery.get('TitleName.csv', function StatList(data){
         var titles = new Array();
         var title_array = jQuery.csv(undefined, undefined, '\r\n')(data);
         for (var i=0; i<title_number.length; i++){
             for (var j = 1; j< title_array.length; j++){
                 var tmp_compare = title_array[j].slice(0,title_array[j].length-1);
                 if(tmp_compare.toString() == title_number[i]){
                     var title = title_array[j][(title_array[j].length-1)];
                     titles.push(title);
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         handleTitleData(titles);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, when you call an asynchronous function, JavaScript will continue its normal execution, *without waiting* for it to complete, thus it will return before `titles` is defined. In order to get the result of the asynchronous call, you can use a [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object:

```
function titlename(title_number) {   
    return jQuery.get('TitleName.csv').pipe(function (data) { 
        var titles = new Array();
        var title_array = jQuery.csv(undefined, undefined, '\r\n')(data);
        for (var i=0; i<title_number.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j< title_array.length; j++) {
                var tmp_compare = title_array[j].slice(0,title_array[j].length-1);
                if(tmp_compare.toString() == title_number[i]){
                    var title = title_array[j][(title_array[j].length-1)];
                    //console.log(title);
                    titles.push(title);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return titles;
    });
}

titlename([1,2,3]).done(function(titles) {
  // do what you want with the returned titles
}).fail(function() {
  // deal with a failure in getting the .csv
});
```